# How to pass a property from one function to another in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, fetch

Im trying to get the email of the user that from the function getFirstApi() and pass it in to getSecondApit() so i can use it as a param in the fetch() request.

**My Code:**

```
 getFirstApi() {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((user) => {
      this.setState({email: user.attributes.email, formemail: user.attributes.email})
      return email
    });
 }

  getSecondApi() {
    fetch(`https://ezha2ns0bl.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/userdata?foo=${encodeURIComponent(email)}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        console.log("THIS IS RESULT" + email),
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            firstname: result.Item.userFirstName,
            middlename: result.Item.userMiddleName,
            surname: result.Item.userLastName,
            city: result.Item.userCity,
            postcode: result.Item.userPostcode,
            state: result.Item.userState,
            about: result.Item.userAbout,

            formfirstname: result.Item.userFirstName,
            formmiddlename: result.Item.userMiddleName,
            formsurname: result.Item.userLastName,
            formcity: result.Item.userCity,
            formpostcode: result.postcode,
            formstate: result.Item.userState,
            formabout: result.Item.userAbout,
            
          });
          console.log("THIS IS RESULT" + result)} ,
      )
  }
```

**My componentDidMount**

```
   componentDidMount() {

    this.getFirstApi();
    this.getSecondApi();

  }
```

This url api call works in my browser, so i assume its what i  need my out come to be.

```
https://ezha2ns0bl.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/userdata?userEmail=%22gitigol723@hapremx.com%22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure to return the `Promise` of your first API call. Then you can use it's result when that has completed.

```
// Where you call your APIs:
getFirstApi().then(email => {
  getSecondApi(email);
});


// Return the API Promise in the first API
 getFirstApi() {
    // notice the 'return' statement here
    return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((user) => {
      this.setState({email: user.attributes.email, formemail: user.attributes.email})
      return email
    });
 }

  // add the email parameter to the method signature
  getSecondApi(email) {
    fetch(`https://ezha2ns0bl.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/userdata?foo=${encodeURIComponent(email)}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        console.log("THIS IS RESULT" + email),
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            firstname: result.Item.userFirstName,
            middlename: result.Item.userMiddleName,
            surname: result.Item.userLastName,
            city: result.Item.userCity,
            postcode: result.Item.userPostcode,
            state: result.Item.userState,
            about: result.Item.userAbout,

            formfirstname: result.Item.userFirstName,
            formmiddlename: result.Item.userMiddleName,
            formsurname: result.Item.userLastName,
            formcity: result.Item.userCity,
            formpostcode: result.postcode,
            formstate: result.Item.userState,
            formabout: result.Item.userAbout,
            
          });
          console.log("THIS IS RESULT" + result)} ,
      )
  }
```

Comment: Im not sure where im suppose to put the first bit of code ? it gets syntax errors. Do you mean in my componentDidmount

Comment: call it in the fetch function ? im confused

Comment: you should call getFirstApi() in componentDidMount.
the result of the that function is a `Promise`. So you can chain the call to `getSecondApi` in the  `.then` part. So: `componentDidMount() { this.getFirstApi().then(email => this.getSecondApi(email)); }`

Comment: email is undefined